# MFC Image List Create ILC_COLORDDB Messing up Highlight

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, imagelist

In MFC, when I create an image list, using these flags:

```
m_ImageListThumb.Create(0x20, 0x20, ILC_COLORDDB | ILC_COLOR32, 0, 1);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYEQ9.png]

```
m_ImageListThumb.Create(0x20, 0x20, ILC_COLOR32, 0, 1);
```

This ways shows correctly

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyTSj.png]

I seem to need to use ILC_COLORDDB, otherwise sometimes highlighting an image with alpha won't show the highlighted blue at all. But my question is how to fix the blue overlay to be smooth, so it's not grainy, when using ILC_COLORDDB.

How do I fix this so ILC_COLORDDB gives a nice smooth blue highlight on click.

Answer (score 0):

`ILC_COLORDDB` and `ILC_COLOR32` are mutually exclusive, you can't use both flags. Look at their values:

```
#define ILC_COLORDDB 0x000000FE
#define ILC_COLOR32  0x00000020
```

If `ILC_COLORDDB` is specified the imagelist uses a bitmap created with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` that is compatible with the current display, so the results you get from this will vary with your current display settings.

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I'm using Windows 8 to run the application.  Any idea why using ILC_COLOR32 would get a nice blue, while CreateCompatibleBitmap wouldn't?

Comment: No, actually that seems strange since Win8 doesn't support less than 32 bpp, you would expect the compatible bitmap to end up as 32 bpp as well. But I suggest rather than trying to use `ILC_COLORDDB` you just use `ILC_COLOR32` and try to solve your alpha problem (you may need to post another question for this though).